# How to show this is decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I'd like to show $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i((n+1)-i)} $$ is decreasing for n>1, which is Cauchy product of $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$$ Numerical computation until n=50 shows it's decreasing but I couldn't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i(n+1-i)}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{n+1-i}\right)=\frac{2 H_n}{n+1},\tag{1}$$
and provided that $n> 1$,
$$ A_n-A_{n+1} = \frac{2(H_n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)} > 0.\tag{2}$$